# Use social login with Jhipster without OpenID Connect server

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jhipster, social-authentication

I generated a simple Jhipster application with jwt, and I would like to use Social login, but I don't want to use the OpenID Connect server (Keycloak or Okta). I just need a simple social login with Google/Github/ etc. How can I do this?